# Can play games on safe mode?

Tags: windows-7

Can i play **AAA title games** on the ***safe mode*** in ***windows 7 32 bit***? like GTA 5, Call of Duty kind of games ?

Comment: Would you tell us why you want it? It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295) to me.

Comment: I agree.  What problem are you facing, that you think running a game in Safe Mode might solve?  I think it's unlikely that most AAA games would run in safe mode, but it's entirely possible that there are other ways to get whatever safe mode is meant to give you.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Safe Mode loads Windows with a minimal driver configuration. That means it will load a graphic driver with only rudimentary 3d support. Most games with 3d graphics will not run in Windows Safe Mode.